# redefine componentWillReceiveProps in external component

Tags: reactjs

I have a module:

```
import {ReferenceInputController} from 'ra-core'
```

I need to redefine it's **`componentWillReceiveProps`**, but I don't want to copy entire component and make it custom. Is there a more easy way to redefine it? Something like creating a new component which extends the `ReferenceInputController` etc ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ReferenceInputController` extends `React.Component`, then you should be able to achieve this using regular class inheritance.

To illustrate this, consider the following `Foo` class. 
Here you can see that it extends the base class `ReferenceInputController`, while also providing custom logic for `componentWillReceiveProps`. This custom logic will be used in place of the equivalent `componentWillReceiveProps` method that was defined in `ReferenceInputController`:

```
class Foo extends ReferenceInputController {

    /* 
       Redefinition of componentWillReceiveProps logic for Foo extension
       of ReferenceInputController base class goes here
    */
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        console.log('Custom logic for Foo that is run during componentWillReceiveProps');
    }

    /*
    The render method defined in your ReferenceInputController base class, as well as 
    any other component lifecycle methods defined in ReferenceInputController will be 
    invoked when Foo is rendered

    render() {
        ...
    }
    */
}
```

You would then use (or render) `Foo` just as you would use `ReferenceInputController`:

```
<div>
   <Foo ... />
</div>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/112891/) if you'd like to see this in action

Comment: Yes I understand this, but i need to override CWRP in ReferenceInputController , not to invoke one more, and if I define

class Foo extends ReferenceInputController 

With it's own CWRP it doesn't override the on in ReferenceInputController
plus Foo doesn't have methods of ReferenceInputController

Comment: I've just run another test - I'm not sure what I'm misunderstanding in your question, as my answer seems to work as you require. Please see updated answer above with link to jsFiddle jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/112891 - does this jsFiddle work for you?